# Time remaining to the next 5 minutes - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the time remaining for the next 5 minutes (snapped to the full 5 minutes of the current time e.g., 15:05, 15:10..)

I was able to achieve the same for the time remaining for next Hour (Not minutes):

```
<span class="timer"></span>
<script>
function secondPassed() {
    var cur_date = new Date();
    var hour = cur_date.getHours();
    var minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
    var minutes_remain = parseInt(59 - parseInt(minutes));
    var seconds_remain = parseInt(60 - parseInt(seconds));

    var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        timers[i].innerHTML = minutes_remain+":"+seconds_remain;
    }

}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
</script>
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ov0oo5f7/

Comment: So what's the problem then ?

Comment: I need it to give the time remaining for the next five min not for the next hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function secondPassed() {
    var cur_date = new Date();
    var minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
    
    var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        timers[i].innerHTML = (4 - minutes % 5) + ":" + (seconds >= 50 ? "0" : "") + (59 - seconds);
    }
    
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="timer"></span>
```

Comment: Oh my bad, I changed it to 10 since I sped up the date variable for testing purposes and I forgot to change it back. Thank you

Comment: great. Any chance to get the seconds synced with the machine time instead of parseInt(60 - parseInt(seconds)); so it goes more accurate?

Comment: Don't know exactly how to explain but when the second ticks there is time difference in milliseconds from the actual local time

Comment: If I understand you correctly then this would sync the interval, if you change the last line to this: `setTimeout(function() {var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);},1000 - new Date() % 1000);`

Comment: @mediaroot—that will go close for the first call, but it will drift after that and occasionally skip a second.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the code a bit and to make it more accurate, use *setTimeout* and call the function as close as reasonable to the next full second. *setInterval* will slowly drift.

```
// Return the time to next 5 minutes as m:ss
function toNext5Min() {

  // Get the current time
  var secs = (new Date() / 1000 | 0) % 300;

  // Function to add leading zero to single digit numbers
  function z(n){return (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;}

  // Return m:ss
  return (5 - secs/60 | 0) + ':' + z(60 - (secs%60 || 60));
}

// Call the function just after the next full second
function runTimer() {
  console.log(toNext5Min());
  var now = new Date();
  setTimeout(runTimer, 1020 - now % 1000);
}
```

The above ticks over on the full minute so that at say 10:00:00 it shows 5:00. If you'd rather is showed 0:00, then the last line of *toNext5Min* should be:

```
  return (5 - (secs? secs/60 : 5) | 0) + ':' + z(60 - (secs%60 || 60));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to change to get it to work the way you want:

```
var minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
var seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
```

try change it to this:

```
var minutes_remain = 5 - minutes%5 - 1;
var seconds_remain = 59 - seconds;
```

Try it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq3spxun/3/)

Comment: great. Any chance to get the seconds synced with the machine time instead of parseInt(60 - parseInt(seconds)); so it goes more accurate?

Comment: JavaScript uses the clients time with new Date(), so this should be accurate. On a second thought, you don't need the parseInt() here since Date().getSeconds() returns an int. 

The clock is now ticking from 60-1 seconds, i've updated it to 59-0 and it should look more accurate.

Comment: Many thanks for explanation. Any chance to force the format to be always MM:SS because currently if the remaining time is 04:01 it display it as 4:1

Comment: Try this: `timers[i].innerHTML = (minutes_remain < 10 ? "0" : "") +  minutes_remain + ":" + (seconds_remain < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds_remain;`

Answer (score 0):

Change your minutes remain to following line. It calculates current minute mod by 5 subtracted from 5, which is what you need.

```
function secondPassed() {
    var cur_date = new Date();
    var hour = cur_date.getHours();
    var minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
    var minutes_remain = parseInt(5 - parseInt(minutes%5));
    var seconds_remain = parseInt(60 - parseInt(seconds));

    var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        timers[i].innerHTML = minutes_remain+":"+seconds_remain;
    }

}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ov0oo5f7/2/

Comment: great. Any chance to get the seconds synced with the machine time instead of parseInt(60 - parseInt(seconds)); so it goes more accurate?

Comment: Your code will goes minus after the 5 minutes complete

Answer (score 0):

You can work out what the next 5 minutes interval will be if you divide by 5, round it up, and multiply by 5 again.

You need to handle if you are on an exact minute otherwise `minutes_remain` will show as 1 minute less.

In terms of being accurate, you don't need to `parseInt` everywhere as they are all numbers already. I've tried to make it as efficient as possible. In any case, you are only checking it once a second, so you can't guarantee accuracy.

http://jsfiddle.net/ov0oo5f7/6/

```
function secondPassed() {
    var cur_date = new Date();

    var hour = cur_date.getHours();

    // handle 0 seconds - would be 60 otherwise
    var seconds_remain = 60 - (cur_date.getSeconds() || 60);

    // handle ceil on 0 seconds - otherwise out by a minute
    var minutes = cur_date.getMinutes() + (seconds_remain == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    var minutes_remain = Math.ceil(minutes/5) * 5 - minutes;

    var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        timers[i].innerHTML = minutes_remain+":"+seconds_remain;
    }

}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the mechine time and counting it down for 5 minutes , then this might help -

```
var startTime = new Date();
function secondPassed() {

    var cur_date = new Date();

    if(parseInt((cur_date - startTime)/1000) >300 ){
        window.clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    }
    var hour = cur_date.getHours();
    var minutes = cur_date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = cur_date.getSeconds();
    var minutes_remain = parseInt(59 - parseInt(minutes));
    var seconds_remain = parseInt(60 - parseInt(seconds));

    var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timer');
    for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
        timers[i].innerHTML = minutes_remain+":"+seconds_remain;
    }

}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is nothing that 5 minutes are 5*60*1000 milliseconds, thus

```
var k = 5*60*1000;
var next5 = new Date(Math.ceil((new Date).getTime()/k)*k);
```